# Php How to convert the following code to array

Tags: php

I have the following code returned from another site.

```
{"balance":200}
```

i have tried

```
$v = {"balance":200};
$t = json_decode($v,true);
```

but i cant access the array with the key

```
$t['balance'];
```

or

```
$v->balance;
```

can anyone help me on how to access it?

Comment: Your example won't work because of missing quotes but otherwise [it works for me](https://eval.in/884693). Do a `var_dump($t)` like I do in my example to make sure the response you are getting matches your expectations.

Comment: You have to wrap the JSON data with quotes like this: `$v = '{"balance":200}';`

Comment: tjat json as i said comes from another site so i have no control on placing the quotes, shoulnt php do this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an error in the syntax!

```
$v = {"balance":200};
```

{} these characters are interpreted in no way by json.

```
 $v = "{'balance':'200'}";
```

a so it should work
read about syntax
[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) or [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm)

Comment: Changing `200` to `'200'` means that you change the value type from `int` to `string`...

Comment: yes, but in php the interpreter will try to do this type int and if type is important to him, then he can not write as a string

Comment: Sorry, but that is not correct. The php interpreter will create a variable of the type you tell it to. `200` will lead to a variable of type `int`, `'200'` will leand to a variable of type `string`. That is a difference. The OPs example uses `200`, you changed it. _Why?_

Comment: but when you try to use it as int, the interpreter will make it int

Comment: It will, but that is risky, since that might lead to unexpected results if the variables value does contain something else apart from digits in the string. Apart from that it requires two type conversions without any reason for that. Again: _why?_ Besides: the json string is not generated by the OP, it is received. So the OP cannot simply change it...

Answer (score 0):

What you yourself tried is fine if you fix a few syntax issue.

Have a try with this compact example:

```
<?php var_dump(json_decode('{"balance":200}')->balance);
```

The output of above code line is:

```
int(200)
```

---

UPDATE:

If you have the json formatted string as a value of a variable, then you can use those lines:

```
<?php 
$json = '{"balance":200}';
$data = json_decode($json)->balance;
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: assume the {"balance":200} is generated from another site and is what I see on print_r the response how will the above code look like

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by your comment, I can only assume that you ask for a more explicit variant of the code. I posted a compact variant to demonstrate the basic principle, certainly you can follow other strategies. I added a variant to the answer. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a valid JSON syntax before decoding, please try that:

```
<?php

$v = '{"balance":200}';
$t = json_decode($v,true);

var_dump($t);
```

Where `{"balance":200}` is your valid json

Answer (score -1):

The following code works perfectly.

```
$str   = file_get_contents(another site url); // output is '{"balance":200}' [without surrounding quotes]
$t_arr = json_decode($str, true);
$t_obj = json_decode($str);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($t_arr); echo "</pre>";
echo "<br>";
echo $t_arr['balance'];
echo "<br>";
echo $t_obj->balance;
```